# In Visual Studio Code ( VS Code ) is there a way to have comments of different colors in the same document? (i.e. for different topics | people)

Tags: comments, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Example:
Alicia and Bob are writing code together.
Alicia makes comments and they show up as green.
Bob makes comments and they show up as pink.

Potential Solution Concept that probably doesn't exist:
When Alicia comments, Alicia uses "/* comment here */" and text is green.
When Bob comments, Bob uses /*. comment here .*/ and text is pink.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the extension [Better Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments) for that.

Then, in your settings.json file you can add the rules for Alicia and Bob, as such:

```
{
    "better-comments.tags": [
        {
            "tag": "Alicia",
            "color": "#70C7CA",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        },
        {
            "tag": "Bob",
            "color": "#C792EA",
            "strikethrough": false,
            "underline": false,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent",
            "bold": false,
            "italic": false
        }
}
```

You can then personalise colors and styles, and create as many tags as you want.

After that, comments that start with "Alicia" or "Bob" will have their corresponding styles.

You may need to reload VSCode for these to apply.

And mind that both Alicia and Bob need to have that extension, and configured to display the styled tags on both computers.